# Is there an IList in java and how to use it and when?

Tags: java

I saw a classes diagram to implement in Java that uses IList as some attributes, I saw IList in #C and some other languages that I know nothing about. I searched for IList in java but I don't find much results.. does it exist in Java?

Comment: What is an `IList` in C# ? Interface of List ? Then `List` is the interface.

Answer (score 2):

In Java there's [java.util.List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html), also an interface, just with no leading "I".

`public interface List<E> extends Collection<E>`

`List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();`

You'll rarely extend it but rather use one of its implementations from the JDK, which most likely will be [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). You'd use the `List` type perhaps for variables but more often in method/function signatures to keep them on a more abstract level. `Collection` also often may do.

There are plenty of [tutorials](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/list.html) out there about lists.